# Needing JavaScript Statements Explanation ( 'this' and 'event')

Tags: javascript, html

**Hey guys!**

Okay today I'm gonna ask about how the specific JavaScript statements `this` and `event` work in a layman's term.

In your own words; please describe the two statements and how they can be used on specific html components.

I only vaguely know how the `event` statement work. And from what I could understand is that it just states an event but once the event has passed it looses all its data and restarts so that on the next time it is used, it can start fresh and the most recent event that uses it will not remember its own past. For me it's basically a chicken pushed into crossing the road but when it was done it was suddenly transported back in time to where it first started; not able to remember anything. Either that or it's the chicken Heihei from Moana.

However, my understanding is only vague because all I found on the `event` statement were too complex or too vague. If anyone could add into this it would be really great.

And then there is the `this` statement.
I don't understand that one at all.
So... how can i use it to get its containing HTML element's properties like the `id`, `name`, `value`, and etc.?

For example:

```
    <input type="button" id="demo" name="dono" value="dem" onclick="caller(event)"/>
    <input type="button" id="demo2" name="dono2" value="dem2" onclick="caller(event)"/>

<script>
    function caller(event){
    //How can you get the id, name, and value of the element that called this event?
    }
</script>
```

If anyone has an explanation please share it.
And don't be vague about your answer.
And yes just putting a link without explaining is considered a vague answer.

This is a conversational question that I'm hoping someone would answer and shed some light into the question.

Comment: Okay i know i'm dumb at JavaScript but that's only cause i'm just a beginner. I'm not really experienced in the deeper side of this language so geez have mercy on me guys. And also the word "layman" means newb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
<input type="button" id="demo" name="dono" value="dem" onclick="caller(this)"/>
    <input type="button" id="demo2" name="dono2" value="dem2" onclick="caller(this)"/>

<script>
    function caller(event){
    console.log(event.target.id);
    console.log(event.name);
    console.log(event.value);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's either `this.id` or `event.target.id`

Comment: or for IE 8 and below `event.srcElement.id`

Comment: oh now i get it... but it's weird how people just downgraded my question like 3 times in less than 7 mins without even explaining why.